# How to let user enter a value in PlSql in Oracle live server?

Tags: oracle, plsql

***Procedure definition :***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DISPLAY_PRODUCT(numpr IN integer,info OUT produit%ROWTYPE)
IS
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO info FROM produit WHERE produit.numprod = numpr; 
END;
/
```

***The main program :***

```
DECLARE
display produit%ROWTYPE;
product_number integer := &product_number ;
BEGIN
   DISPLAY_PRODUCT(product_number,display);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('numero : '||display.numprod || 'nom : '||display.nomprod);
END;
/
```

How can i enter a value for **product_number** varaible (& doesn't work ) ?

***And i get errors :***

```
Procedure created.
   ORA-06550: line 3, column 31:
   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specif
```

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a question template greatly increases your chance of getting a satisfactory. In this case specifically what have you tried and what result did you get?

Comment: Thank you , I edited the post

Comment: It's in [the Live SQL FAQs](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:HELP:7358755146057::NO:::): **Q:Can I use input parameters?** A: No, we do not support input parameters at runtime.

Comment: @APC Yeah ,Okay Thank you man !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, the answer is simple: you can't do that.